# Two Radio Groups in NSIS dialogue

Tags: nsis, radio-group

I have a dialogue page in an NSIS installer on which I want to have 2 radio button groups, with 3 radio buttons in each group.

Each group is independent, and a selection is required in both groups.

I have the following code, which shows 2 groups being created with 3 buttons each, but when the installer runs all 6 buttons are grouped as 1 group which mean I can only select 1 from 6, rather than 1 from 3 buttons in each group.

```
Function settingsTypePageCreate
   nsDialogs::Create 1018
   pop $0

   ; Radio Group 1

   ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 0 0 100% 40u "Select Method for specifying file locations"    
   Pop $1
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 10% 100% 15u "Use Environment Variable."
   pop $2
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25% 100% 15u "Use central config file."
   pop $3
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 40% 100% 15u "Use default %USERPROFILE%."
   pop $4

   ; Radio Group 2

   ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 0 60% 100% 40u "Select location folder"    
   Pop $5
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 70% 100% 15u "%APPDATA%"
   pop $6
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 80% 100% 15u "%USERPROFILE%"
   pop $7
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 90% 100% 15u "PROGRAMDATA"
   pop $8

   nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Also, I cannot find anywhere a description of how the position and size parameters for NSD_Create. I'm having to do it by trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WS_GROUP` style is used to create grouped controls:

> [`WS_GROUP` Specifies the first control of a group of controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czada357.aspx) in which the user can move from one control to the next with the arrow keys. All controls defined with the `WS_GROUP` style FALSE after the first control belong to the same group. The next control with the `WS_GROUP` style starts the next group (that is, one group ends where the next begins).

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Function settingsTypePageCreate
   nsDialogs::Create 1018
   pop $0

   ; Radio Group 1
   ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 0 0 100% 50u "Select Method for specifying file locations"    
   Pop $0
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5u 12u 70% 12u "Use Environment Variable."
   pop $2
   ${NSD_AddStyle} $2 ${WS_GROUP}
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5u 24u 70% 12u "Use central config file."
   pop $3
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5u 36u 70% 12u "Use default %USERPROFILE%."
   pop $4

   ; Radio Group 2
   ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 0 60u 100% 50u "Select location folder"    
   Pop $0
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5u 72u 70% 12u "%APPDATA%"
   pop $6
   ${NSD_AddStyle} $6 ${WS_GROUP}
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5u 84u 70% 12u "%USERPROFILE%"
   pop $7
   ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5u 96u 70% 12u "PROGRAMDATA"
   pop $8

   nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Page Custom settingsTypePageCreate
Page InstFiles
```

The measurements are described in the [nsDialogs documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html):

> Each of the measurements that the macros take can use one of three unit types - pixels, [dialog units](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226789(v=vs.85).aspx) or percentage of the dialog's size. It can also be negative to indicate it should be measured from the end. To use dialog units, the measurement must be suffixed with the letter u. To use percentage, the measurement must be suffixed with the percentage sign - %. Any other suffix, or no suffix, means pixels.
>
> Dialog units allow creation of dialogs that scale well when different fonts or DPI is used. Its size in pixels is determined at runtime based on the font and the DPI.